# Executing SQL queries in Eclipse concole

Tags: sql, eclipse, jdbc

I have a sql text file containing all the queries (ie. create table etc). I do not want to use java program to execute the queries. Is there a way I can run all the queries in Eclipse?

Comment: You might be able to do something using the [Eclipse Data Tools Project](https://eclipse.org/datatools/)